# How do I solve simultaneous exponential equations without logarithm

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponentiation

I had a question from my book

$$(3^x+1)-(2^y+1)=1$$

$$4\cdot(3^x)+3\cdot(2^y)=24$$

So without using logarithms, how can I solve it thx

Comment: So, we have two unknowns $3^x, 2^y$ with two variables

Comment: In the first equation, is that $3^x+1$ or $3^{x+1}$?

Comment: Use lab bhattacharjee's hint, but with an aesthetic change: Substitute two new variables, $u,v$, say for $3^x,2^y$. Solve the new equations for $u,v$. Once you have the values for $u,v$, it will be clear what $x,y$ have to be.

Comment: I'd like to see how are you going to solve it using logarithms

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you mean $3^{x+1}$ and $2^{y+1}$. Otherwise the equations will be impossible to solve without using logarithms. Following the assumption that you meant $3^{x+1}$ and $2^{y+1}$,

Let $3^x$ be $a$ and $2^y$ be $b$.

Substitute these in accordingly and we get:

$3a−2b=1$

$4a+3b=24$

Solving simultaneously:

$a=3$ and $b=4$

From there, we simplify the expressions of $a$ and $b$ respectively, and we obtain

$3^x=3^1$ and $2^y=2^2$

We can then derive that $x=1$ and $y=2$.